# Is there an efficient approach to use cell_spec() for multiple combinations of variables in R?

Tags: r, kableextra

I have a data set that contains three variables (`var1`, `var2` and `var3`) and these same ones but in mean and SD form. I'm wanting to produce a conditionally formatted table using `kableextra` by referencing each variable's mean and SD counterpart.

Is there a quicker way to do this for ALL variables (`var1`, `var2` and `var3`) than the example I've included below for `df_kbl`? My real data set contains 8-10 unique metrics, so repeating the same `cell_spec()` steps for each one seems inefficient. Is there a faster approach I can take to do this for `var1`, `var2` and `var3` at the same time? I'd preferably want to avoid any pivoting due to the nuances of the report I'm constructing. Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(
  name = paste("Name", LETTERS[1:10]),
  var1 = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var2 = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var3 = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var1_mean = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var2_mean = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var3_mean = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
  var1_sd = rnorm(10, 5, 0.5),
  var2_sd = rnorm(10, 5, 0.5),
  var3_sd = rnorm(10, 5, 0.5)
  )

df_kbl <- df %>%
  mutate(var1 = cell_spec(
    var1,
    background = case_when(
      var1 > var1_mean + var1_sd ~ "red",
      var1 < var1_mean - var1_sd ~ "green",
      .default = "transparent"
    )
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `across` with `cur_column` and `get`. Additionally I use a small custom convenience function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

set_bg <- function(x, mean, sd) {
  case_when(
    x > mean + sd ~ "red",
    x < mean - sd ~ "green",
    .default = "transparent"
  )
}

df_kbl <- df %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      matches("^var\\d+$"),
      ~ cell_spec(
        .x,
        background = set_bg(
          .x,
          get(paste0(cur_column(), "_mean")),
          get(paste0(cur_column(), "_sd"))
        )
      )
    )
  )

df_kbl |>
  kbl(escape = FALSE)
```

[image]